# Javascript on two pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-console

I'm trying to create a jquery script.

The script need to :

1- Click for a specific link (button) on a list in order to change the page

2- Fill out the text input on the page

3- Valid

(4- and loop...)

The problem is, when I change the page, the script doest execute on the second page.

Here is my script :

```js
window.allButtons = $('a[href^="/discussions/"]')

if ($(allButtons[2]).text()=="Afficher cette discussion"){
    allButtons[2].click();
}

setTimeout(function()

{

    let messages = [
    'Bonjour, je suis désolé mais j\'ai déjà envoyé mon colis avec weeship'
    ];
    function getMessage() {
       return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    }

    $('#message_content').val(getMessage);

    // setTimeout(function(){ 
    //  $('input.button.button--tertiary').click();
    // },1000);

},1000);
```

Please, what's the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the page"? Unless you have some sort of Chrome addon that allows you to execute code over multiple pages, or you are using puppeteer, there isn't really a way to navigate to another page and execute code from the page before there

Comment: I'm using the chrome console. As you can see the script click on the button and the the following of the script doest not execute on the other page.
How can i solve the problem? Using Puppeteer?

Comment: It's pretty easy using puppeteer, yes. But if you run this through the console, why not execute it in steps? Like first, click the button and then introduce the loop?

Comment: Because the i want to automate the script with loops in order to answer every people on the list.

Comment: I need to click here : http://prntscr.com/k8dos5 and then fill this input http://prntscr.com/k8dp1f in loops

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to hold on data from different pages.

Before you leave the page you could set a value as an indicator or the value you actually want with something like that:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

And once the second page load retrieve the necessary information from session storage with something like that

```
// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

You can apply your logic now. If the value `wasRedirected` for example is true it means he came from your redirect so you can check if you have a stored value for the key `theInputValue` and set it to the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anastasios,
Regarding my script, I need to click here : prntscr.com/k8dos5 and then fill this input prntscr.com/k8dp1f in loops. How can i integrate your solution?

Comment: @theovogg what do you mean loop and what is exactly that you don't understand from my suggestion? I give a way to hold on data when changing pages. I can't understand what you want to do from your question or your comment. Please if you need any more clarifications re-write your question and add the entire flow that you want to achieve.